How does the Goldreich-Levin Theorem imply the existence of secure pseudorandom generators?
I am reading the text "Computational Complexity, A Modern Approach". On pg183 it is explained how the Goldreich-Levin theorem implies the existence of a secure pseudorandom generator. The difficulty I have is that the function that is implied to be a secure pseudorandom generator is defined in a way I cannot understand. It is defined as $G(x,r) = f(x),r,x \odot r$, which is notation I can't make sense of. My feeling is that it's a typo but I'm not sure. If it helps, I do understand that $G$ is meant to extend its input by one bit; also, according to the Goldreich-Levin theorem, $x, r \in \{0,1\}^*$, and $f(x): \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}$  is a one-way function such that $f$ is one-to-one and $|f(x)| = |x|$ for every $x \in \{0,1\}^*$
Edit:
The reason the notation $G(x,r) = f(x),r,x \odot r$ confuses me is I'm not sure if $G$ has 3 outputs, $f(x)$, $r$, and $x \odot r$. None of these seems plausible to me because none of the three are 1 bit longer than the concatenation of $x$ and $r$, as is required of $G$: $|f(x)|$ alone cannot be 1 bit longer than the concatenation of $x$ and $r$, because it is stated that $|f(x)| = |x|$; and neither $r$ nor $x$ can be 1 bit longer the concatenation of $x$ and $r$, because, for $x \odot r$ to be defined, $r$ would have to be the same length as $x$; and of course $x \odot r$ cannot be 1 bit longer than $x$, because $\odot$ is componentwise AND. For related reasons, I also don't see how the concatenation of $f(x)$, $r$, and $x \odot r$ could be 1 bit longer than the concatenation of $x$ and $r$. I guess it's the commas in the definition of $G$ that are confusing me

What part of the notation do you understand, and what don't you understand?  It might work better to ask about one element of notation you don't understand (e.g., "$,$" or "$\odot$"), so that this question will be useful to others with a similar question about that notation.  Have you tried doing some research to look for lecture notes that explain the Goldreich-Levin generator?  I suspect there should be lots of other explanations on the web.

It sounds like your issue is just understanding the notation.
Commas indicate concatenation.
$\odot$ denotes the dot product.
So, $f(x)$ is $|x|$ bits long, $r$ is $|x|$ bits long, and $x \odot r$ is 1 bit long.  This means that the input to $G$ is $2|x|$ bits long and the output is $2|x|+1$ bits long, so it stretches its input by one bit.

Okay I see where I went wrong. $x \odot r$ is not component-wise AND. In fact, $x \odot r = \Sigma_i x_i r_i (mod 2)$, and the result of this operation is, by the Goldreich-Levin theorem, unpredictable from $f(x)$ and $r$. Thus $G$, by appending $x \odot r$ to its input, $( x, r )$, outputs a pseudorandom string that is one bit longer than its input, provided $G$'s input is random or pseudorandom.
Still, the commas used in the definition of $G$ confound me. However, understanding that notation is not necessary for understanding the Goldreich-Levin theorem's implication that secure pseudorandom generators exist.
